# 2 random images but not the same one

Tags: javascript

I have this function that shows two random images picked from a folder. Is there any chance I can modify the code so that I won't have the same image twice as result?

Thanks in advance.

```
var theImages = new Array()

theImages[0] = 'img/dyptichs/f-1.jpg'
theImages[1] = 'img/dyptichs/f-2.jpg'
theImages[2] = 'img/dyptichs/f-3.jpg'
theImages[3] = 'img/dyptichs/f-4.jpg'
theImages[4] = 'img/dyptichs/f-5.jpg'

var j = 0
var p = theImages.length;
var preBuffer = new Array()
for (i = 0; i < p; i++){
   preBuffer[i] = new Image()
   preBuffer[i].src = theImages[i]
}
var WI1 = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-1));
var WI2 = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-2));

function showImage1(){
document.write('<img src="'+theImages[WI1]+'">');
}
function showImage2(){
document.write('<img src="'+theImages[WI2]+'">');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var WI1 = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-1));
var WI2 = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-1));
while (WI2 === WI1) {
    WI2 = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-1));
}
```

We keep generating a new number until it's different from WI1, ensuring it is unique.

Answer (score 2):

The way I'd personally handle that is to randomise the array and then just grab the first 2 entries. That way you still pick 2 at random, but you guarantee not to get the same 2.

```
var theImages = new Array()

theImages[0] = 'img/dyptichs/f-1.jpg'
theImages[1] = 'img/dyptichs/f-2.jpg'
theImages[2] = 'img/dyptichs/f-3.jpg'
theImages[3] = 'img/dyptichs/f-4.jpg'
theImages[4] = 'img/dyptichs/f-5.jpg'

var randomImages = theImages
    .concat()
    .sort(function () {

        return Math.random() > 0.5
            ? 1
            : -1;

    })
    .slice(0, 2);

function showImage1() {
    document.write('<img src="' + randomImages[0] + '">');
}

function showImage2() {
    document.write('<img src="' + randomImages[1] + '">');
}
```

*Edit: including the original array for a complete solution*

Comment: Where would you put the array though?

Comment: @Federico sorry, I don't understand the question. `randomImages` is the array, it's in the current scope (which looks like the global scope to me). Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yeah but the images are inside a folder and here it's not specified?

Comment: They're already specified in `theImages`. All I'm doing is creating a version of the `theImages` array with a random order and calling it `randomImages`

Comment: Sort with random comparator is not the correct way to shuffle a sequence, as it will not give uniformly random results.

Comment: @riv you're absolutely right. I wanted a simple solution to explain quickly, but there are much better shuffling solutions around. For example in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/557019

Answer (score 1):

```
var WI1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*p);
var WI2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*(p-1));
if (WI2 >= WI1) {
  WI2 += 1;
}
```

Use floor instead of round and subtract 1, because with round you get twice less chance to get first or last element.

The if trick is slightly better than a loop in this case, though the loop is easier to apply to a more complex case.

Comment: index out of bounds if WI1 is 4

Comment: It can't be 4 because random can't be 1.